# Exporting User logins to firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to know if there is a method of exporting user login credentials (from CSV or JSON)
 to firebase authentication. 
Basically, I am coming up with an app where companies can pre-assign username and password and will pass this info to me on Excel CSV or JSON format. I wanted to know if there is a way of exporting this data straight to firebase authentication.

Also, I wanted to know if there is a way to create a different database for every new company and keep the login system the same on the App.

It might sound vague but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create these user accounts through a few ways:

1. The Firebase CLI, which has a [`auth:import` command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth).
2. The Firebase Admin SDK, which has [`createUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#create-user) and [`importUser` methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#import-users).